# Where can I get official Windows XP .iso image files?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

These used to be available in Microsoft's website but are no more there because XP got abandoned.

I need either one of these, official image only (in order of preference):

-Windows XP Professional SP3 64-bit

-Windows XP Professional SP2 64-bit

-Windows XP Home SP3 64-bit

-Windows XP Home SP2 64-bit

-Other Windows XP 64-bit

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/88459/313985

Answer (score -1, accepted):

u cant get the official image as microsoft has stopped support for windows xp in April 8, 2014 . Sorry :(

Comment: Well, the old images must still be floating around somewhere right?

Comment: yea for example this torrent https://monova.org/torrent/40827825/windows-xp-professional-64-bit-sp3-iso.html but please be careful while downloading torrents as some torrent files may contain viruses

Comment: microsoft has stop providing Windows XP. But you can find https://offlineinstallersofts.com/windows-xp-sp3-iso-free-download-full-version.html